# How can I programmatically tell if my Node application is being ran by Nodemon?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I want to include some additional debugging information if my Node.js application is being ran by Nodemon. Is there some variable that is set when my application is being ran by Nodemon instead of just Node?

Comment: Check your parent process ID?

Comment: It might be easier to just set a env var when you run nodemon? `DEBUG=true nodemon whatever.js`